# Need help creating enemies in a Java game

Tags: java

Right now I'm making (actually copying) a game quite similar to Brick breaker like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2B2j.png)

And this is the code for the bricks:

```
public class MapGenerator {
public int map[][];
public int brickWidth;
public int brickHeight;

public MapGenerator(int row, int col) {
    map = new int[row][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
            map[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    brickWidth = 540 / col;
    brickHeight = 150 / row;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
            if (map[i][j] > 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillRect(j * brickWidth + 80, i * brickHeight + 50, brickWidth, brickHeight);

                g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawRect(j * brickWidth + 80, i * brickHeight + 50, brickWidth, brickHeight);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setBrickValue(int value, int row, int col) {
    map[row][col] = value;
}
```

The problem is I don't want it to be simple white bricks, I want the objects on the screen to be enemies, and when the ball touches them they disappear (basically behaving like bricks). But I really don't know how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It's difficult to help you with such a generic question. Are you looking to draw an image instead of a brick? Then try googling something like 'java graphics2d image' that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: You're going to have to replace your bricks with sprites. There are any number of existing resources online which describe sprites and sprite animation, so fire up your favorite search engine and start reading.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you're getting at is that instead of a *simple* rectangle object, you want an image of something else, an enemy in your case. Fortunately, there are lots of ways to go about this (and even more resources available!), but I suggest using Sprites (which in this case are actually just images).
Here is an example that applies to you:

[Example](https://zetcode.com/javagames/breakout/)

[Github](https://github.com/janbodnar/Java-Breakout-Game)